# Using img with a file:// in Chrome

Tags: html, image

i'm having an img on a file server problem.

My images are stored on a server within our environment. it has to be this server, and this server does not have a web-server on it. i need to access the files from the smb path, such as:

```
\\server\storage\file.png
```

this works fine in IE, when i make the tag:

```
<img style="width: 100%;" src="file:////server/storage/file.png"/>
```

However, this does not work in chrome... the image just doesn't display.

help please?

Answer (score 2):

Seems this is issue with Chrome, check this

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40415